# Configurations, Registry and Language names conventions

Tags: php, naming-conventions

Well, here's a great question that has always disturbed me.

**Introduction**

I'm developing a web application that should be multi-language and customizable.
So i developed a registry-class (that will group my internal configurations) and a language class that will take care of getting the right language file (based on the browser language) and get the language string i need.

**Let's get deeper**

Let's talk about the use of this classes

```
# config.reg.php
self::set('configuration-name');
# whatever-file.php
reg::get('configuration-name');
```

The same piece of code is used for the language class which will have a

```
# it.lang.php
self::set('duck-you', 'Daffanculo');
# en.lang.php
self::set('duck-you', 'Duck you');
# whatever-file.php
lang::get('duck-you');
```

**The real matter**

Ok, now. I'm always pretty much d*cked while choosing the right name for the configurations and for the language indexes, and I always end up with something like:

```
self::set('that-error-message-that-appear-when-a-user-is-not-logged-in');
```

Or:

```
self::set('your-login-action-has-encountered-a-problem-please-get-back-later');
```

for languages, and:

```
self::set('that-cookie-name-used-in-X-file');
```

for configurations.
...wich is not that great.

**Final question**

So i was wondering, are there any names conventions that could help me getting trough this and move on?

Comment: Are you sure you said "the original F word" enough in your post? I'm sure it could've used a little more cussing.

Comment: Does that word disturbs you? I thought you were older enough to move on this childish-behavior i have. Also there should be no kid over here, and we should be all adults, so what's the real matter? (Notice that kids do know the meaning of that word)

Comment: @Charlie: I'm an adult and I don't see any reason to use profanity here. Personally I think it's more childish to needlessly use bad language than not to.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen, I think that 'duck-you' is funny. I personally hate people who cannot stands some words just because our bigot-era has decided to put these words in the taboo-drawer. Also I didn't meant to hurt anyone anyway. It was just for fun. So, with all due respect, relax: it's just a word.

Comment: @Charlie: I don't hate the words - I only hate when they're used without a reason.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen, ok so. I guess you have enough reputation to gain my respect on your decisions. Also i don't want to go too off-topic. I would be glad to discuss about the "swearing-philosophy". Not here though.

Comment: @Charlie sorry, no cursing on SO.  Unless you get away with it.  That's the policy, please follow it.  If you actually want to discuss it, go over to [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=cursing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for starters your language values should not be encapsulated in your registry object.

your registry object should only contain objects such as Session, Language, Input, output etc, so your static class should be build like so:

```
abstract class Registry
{
    public static function get($key)
    {
    }

    public static function set($key,$object)
    {
    }
}
```

then you would insert your objects into the Registry like so:

```
Registry::set("Language", new Language());
```

You should then use your language class to fetch your language files:

```
$Language = Registry::get("Language");
$Message = $Language->get("YourMessageKey");
```

in regards to naming conventions I would advice you to use all lowercase, and underscores only (this is for clarity)

so the following line:

```
that-error-message-that-appear-when-a-user-is-not-logged-in
```

would become

```
that_error_message_that_appear_when_a_user_is_not_logged_in
```

but this is way to long and pointless, what you should do is have your language multi-dimensional so that the error messages are contained within the error context.

```
$Language->errors("user_not_logged_in");
```

which becomes much more readable and has better performance because you would split your context's up into separate files like so

```
/locale/en/primary.php | loaded by default
/locale/en/errors.php
/locale/en/menu.php
/locale/en/user.php
```

Each would only be loaded when called, for example:

```
$Language->user("welcome_new_user");
/*         ^                      */
```

In your language class create a call method to be able to do this kind of selecting:

```
 public function __call($context,$params)
 {
     if(!$this->contextLoader($context))
     {
         $this->loadContext($context)
     }
     return $this->languages[$this->lid][$context][$params[0]];
 }
```

This will make things much more manageable.

Note:

**Wash your dirty mouth out!**

Comment: What's the utility of a registry class then?

Comment: To give you a greater scope, so anywhere within the application you can get to your objects and to also help with back traces